# Django ImageField.path returns path without upload_to within save method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

Django *ImageField.path* returns path without *upload_to* within *save* method:

```
# models.py
class Message(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='mes-img', null=True, blank=True)

def image_tag(self):
    if self.image:
        # Printing "/base-dir/media/mes-img/image.png"
        print(self.image.path)
        # src=/media/mes-img/image.png
        return mark_safe('<img src="{0}" width="100" />'.format(self.image.url))

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    # Returns "/base-dir/media/image.png", should return "/base-dir/media/mes-img/image.png"
    print(self.image.path)
    # Returns "/media/image.png", should return "/media/mes-img/image.png"
    print(self.image.url)
```

OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Python 3.6.4

Django 2.0.2

Comment: How do you upload file? Do you use Django form or Django admin panel?

Comment: Django REST Framework and Django admin panel. The same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload_to`  is passed to the `Storage.save()` method, check this part of [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). So `upload_to` will be added to the path only after image will be saved. Try something like this:

```
 def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    print(self.image.path)
    print(self.image.url)
```

`super().save()` will save image instance automatically.

Comment: save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'content'

Comment: @SemperPeritus you need image url before saving model instance? Otherwise you can try updated answer.